# how to manipulate a binary file and write the results into another binary file

Tags: python

I have a binary file and when I parse it in python, the contents will look like this:

```
b'\x00\x20\x00\x2A\x02\x01'
```

the data is presented in pairs and in fact the strings will be represented as byte arrays. I will be effectively dealing with binary data. in the the mentioned example there are 3 pairs (`\x00\x20  \x00\x2A  \x02\x01`). I want to change the input file and then write it into a binary file. the change is as follows:
in every pair, if the 1st item is 0, the 2nd item will be in the output file. if the 1st item is 1, the 2nd item from the previous pair will be in the output file. if the 1st item is greater than 1, then it would be more complicated. it would depend on 2 items in the same pair. for example1, if the 1st item is 2 and the 2nd item is 1, to get the number for the output, the program goes 2 items back in the output and uses that item as the output.
example2: if the 1st item is 2 and the 2nd item is 2, to get the number for the output, the program goes 2 items back in the output and uses that item plus 1 item after that as the output.

here is the expected output:

```
b'\x20\x2A\x20'
```

I tried to that using the following code in python:

```
data = b'\x00\x20\x00\x2A\x02\x01'

out = bytearray()
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i % 2 !=0:
        if data[i] ==0:
        out.append(data[i+1])
        elif data[i] ==1:
        out.append(data[i-1])
        elif data[i] >1:
            n = data[i]
            for j in range(n):
                out.append(n[0:j])
```

but it did not return the expected output. since I am quite new at working with binary files, would you help me to fix it? or give me some tips to get such output?

Comment: It would be good if you could show what output you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

You were not that far. First, `range` allows to automatically only use every n-th item with its step argument so you could use:

```
for i in range(0,len(data),2):
```

Next, the last block in not consistent with your text:

```
        n = data[i]
        for j in range(n):       # according to your text, it should be n = data[i+1]
            out.append(n[0:j])   # non sensible expression: n is an integer
```

To get the expected data, you should use:

```
        n = data[i+1]
        for j in range(n):
            out.append(data[i-3+2*j])
```

But beware, this code blindly trusts the `data`  input to be correct and will raise KeyError if an operation requires an inexistent byte.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to make decisions baes on the **first** item of each pair you should check for `i % 2 == 0` otherwise `data[i]` will always be the second item of your pairs. This is because the counter starts at 0.

You get the error message, because your `n` is an `int` and therefore you can't use slicing (the `[]` operator) on it.

Moreover your code for `data[i] > 1` doesn't fit at all of what you describe in your examples, since you want to go back in the **output**.

It would be more like:

```
data = b'\x00\x20\x00\x2A\x02\x01'

out = bytearray()
for i in range(len(data)):
  if i % 2 == 0:
    if data[i] == 0:
      out.append(data[i+1])
    elif data[i] == 1:
      out.append(data[i-1])
    elif data[i] > 1:
      n = data[i]
      for j in range(n):
        out.append(out[-2])  # take the item 2 steps back from the end of "out"
```

`out` will be a bytearray with the values `[32, 42, 32, 42]`, even though `print(out)` will output `bytearray(b' * *')`

But keep in mind, as @Serge Ballesta already stated in his answer: Your program totally trusts that `data` is formatted correctly and if it is not you will run into problems like an index out of range when `out` is not big enough for `out[-2]`.

Comment: thanks but still does not return the expected output. here is the output of this code:  bytearray(b' * *')

Comment: That is because of the string representation of the bytes. If you run `int.from_bytes(out[0], "big")` you will see the value is the correct 32. You can even add a `print(data)` right at the beginning to see that the string representation does not fit to what you have as input.